# Number of primitive representations?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, sums-of-squares

Here :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

$r_2'(n)$ is a function calculating the number of solutions $a^2+b^2=n$ with integers $a,b$ satisfying $0<a\le b$

> How can I calculate $P(n)$ , which shall be here the number of the primitive solutions ($\gcd(a,b)=1$) of $a^2+b^2=n$ with integers $a,b$ satisfying $0<a\le b$ ?

Some cases are relatively easy :

- If $n$ is odd and squarefree, $\gcd(a,b)$ is necessarily satisfied. Hence we just have $P(n)=r_2'(n)$
- If $n$ is an odd square of a squarefree number $m$ , then it can be shown that $P(n)=P(m)$ holds.

But how can I calculate $P(n)$ in general ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Apparently, the order is ignored, so $(1/2)$ and $(2/1)$ are considered to be the same solution. Also , apparently $0$ is excluded, but $a=b$ apparently allowed.

Comment: After trying some $n$ , for example $2^2\cdot 5^4$ and $2^3\cdot 5^4$, I came to this conclusion.

Comment: Somewhat related posts are [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036010/which-integers-are-a-sum-of-two-relatively-prime-squares) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684909/representation-as-a-sum-of-two-squares).

Comment: $(1)$ In the link with score +2 , the necessary and sufficient condition seems to be that there is no prime factor of the form $4k+3$, but I do not understand why the exponent in $2^a$ can exceed $1$ $(2)$ This does not yet give the number of representations.

Comment: A proof seems to be [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=ktCZ2MvgN3MC&pg=PA390&lpg=PA390&dq=number+of+representations+n%3Da%5E2%2Bb%5E2+as+sum+of+two+coprime+squares&source=bl&ots=DuIy2asnRS&sig=ACfU3U2sZlOMno4-IjolEi8MsiM4tz8Ypw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBhJa-hNHnAhXjoVwKHbDICssQ6AEwDHoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=number%20of%20representations%20n%3Da%5E2%2Bb%5E2%20as%20sum%20of%20two%20coprime%20squares&f=false).

Comment: @DietrichBurde OK, the condition makes sense. It remains to determine the number of solutions , if it is actually satisfied.